# Choose between two cells to copy and paste

Tags: vba

I've only just starting to pick up VBA and Python so forgive my ignorance. I'm trying to code something that can choose between two cells and paste the cell that is not blank.

Currently what i came up with is this:

```
Sub ManualCopyEqual()
    Set wS1 = Sheets("Neptune")
    Set wS2 = Sheets("Contact")

    wS1.Range("U2:U102").Copy
    wS2.Range("R3:R102").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=         False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

This allows me to copy the row U from wS1 and paste to wS2. However, I would like to code something that will enable me to copy information from row V if the cell in row U is empty.

In other words, if U2 is empty, how do I code such that V2 is copied to R3 instead of copying the blank U2 into R3?

Any help would be so much appreciated!! :)

Regards, 
Bills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition to Skaterhaz' answer, you can use a loop to go through a range of cells in the columns, say 1 to 200:

```
Sub Copy_Loop()

Dim i as Long

    For i = 1 to 200
        If wS1.Range("U" & i).Value = "" Then
            wS1.Range("V" & i).Copy Destination:= wS2.Range("R" & (i+1))
        Else
            wS1.Range("U" & i).Copy Destination:= wS2.Range("R" & (i+1))
        End if
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one cell copied then

```
If wS1.Range("U2").Value = "" Then
   wS1.Range("V2").Copy Destination:= wS2.Range("R3")
Else
   wS1.Range("U2").Copy Destination:= wS2.Range("R3")
End if
```

Comment: I was just about to ask. Brilliant!